# How to remove a GET query key in NGINX and use the GET value as the URI?

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have an email verification script that looks like this:

http://example.com/v/index.php?t=TOKEN_EMAILED_TO_CLIENT

And I want it to look like this:

http://example.com/v/TOKEN_EMAILED_TO_CLIENT

Essentially just removing the `index.php?t=` portion of the URL, but still allowing the index.php file to process the token.

I have tried the following three settings and none of them have worked:

```
location /v/ {
    try_files index.php$args;
}
```

The above results in a failed nginx.conf file

```
location ^~ /v/ {
    try_files /v/index.php?q=$uri;
}
```

The above results in a failed nginx.conf file

```
location ^~ /v/ {
    rewrite ^/v/index.php?q=(.*)$ $1 permanent;
}
```

The above passes nginx.conf file requirements, but still does not do what I would like. It shows a 404 error when visiting http://example.com/v/TOKEN_EMAILED_TO_CLIENT

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First two fails because `try_files` requires at least two arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing, `^~` usage is not necessary if you don't have any regex matching this pattern prior to the location your are defining. What you want to do is basically have proper URIs and rewrite them to pass an argument to your php application. In this case, the appropriate solution is using rewrites.

The thing you missed in there is that the URI you are matching against is the first argument to the rewrite directive so it can obviously not match `^/v/index.php?q=(.*)$` since it equals `/v/TOKEN_EMAILED_TO_CLIENT`. The second argument to the rewrite directive is the URI to rewrite to.

So given you have somewhere a location of this kind which handles `.php` files :

```
location ~ \.php$ {
     [ ... ]
}
```

Then you need this location block instead :

```
location /v/ {
    rewrite ^/v/(.*)$ /v/index.php?t=$1? last;
}
```

Comment: That did it, and makes great sense the way you wrote it. Thank you. Can you comment about why the "last" is needed at the end as opposed to "break" or "permanent"?

Comment: `last` causes nginx to start searching for a new `location` block that matches the rewritten URL. `break` just stops processing current `rewrite` rules, and therefore the PHP script doesn't get executed after that. `permanent` returns a `301` redirect HTTP response to the client, and is completely different from the other two options.

Comment: Actually `last` here is redundant. It prevents processing other rewrite rules in current location. And I think you should explain `?` suffix in rewrite's second argument.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, why would I want other rewrite rules being processed when this is a one-off rewrite?

Comment: There is mo other rewrites in this location. Tgat's why it's redundant. It's not an error, but you should understand what's going on

Comment: The `last` directive is indeed not mandatory in this particular case but it's good practice to mention it since if you start adding new rewrite rules and the rewriten URI somehow matches further rewrite rules regex in the same location block then you will end up with results you probably didn't expect. The  question mark added at the end of the rewriten URI prevent nginx from adding additionnal query string parameters from the original URI (which is the default behaviour when rewritting query string parameters).